# Custom Validator - Error message does not display on front end

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, customvalidator

I am trying to use a **CustomValidator** to validate entering of a string - *po box*

Basically, I want the users to avoid typing their postal address in address box for which I have written a function with the regular expression. But the problem is that the error message does not appear though it triggers the function. (I know this because I checked this by placing breakpoints in my Javascript function using Chome developer tools.)

Below is my .ascx file code.

```
<div class="clearfix">
     <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text="Address" AssociatedControlID="txtAddress"
     class="formlabel firstfocus"></asp:Label>

     <div class="input">
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="large" MaxLength="80"></asp:TextBox>

          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valAddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddress"
            CssClass="error-block" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="<p>Address is required</p>"
            SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

           <asp:CustomValidator ID="valAddressPOBOX" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true" ValidateEmptyText="true" ErrorMessage="<p>Cannot contain a PO Box number</p>" ClientValidationFunction="AddressPOBoxValidation" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CustomValidator>                                    

      </div>
</div>
```

The **RequiredFieldValidator** triggers the error message.

Below is the screenshot showing error message triggered from **RequiredFieldValidator**

[image]

With  **CustomValidator** the trigger happens but the error message does not come up. I have checked on other CustomValidators on the same ascx page and made sure this one has properties no different from them, but still, if I am missing on any visibility property, feel free to correct me.

Below are 2 screenshots to show how the effect of **CustomValidator** takes place.

Before entering *po box*

[image]

After entering *po box* (Notice how the gap between address and address 2 increases.)

[image]

Coming on to the Javascript side, below is the function

```
function CheckPOBOXAddress(address) {
    var poboxPattern = /(p\.?\s?o?\.?\s?b\.?(ox)\.?(\s|[0-9])?|post\soffice)/i;


    if (poboxPattern.test(address))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function AddressPOBoxValidation(sender, args) {
    var address = args.Value;

   if (CheckPOBOXAddress(address)) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    } 

    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.After days of trial, error and research this worked for me:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomAddressValidator" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="CheckAddressValidation" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" CssClass="error-block" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True">Cannot contain a PO Box number</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Also I modified my Javascript into a single function :

```
function CheckAddressValidation(sender, args) {
    var address = args.Value;
    var addressPattern = /(p\.?\s?o?\.?\s?b\.?(ox)\.?(\s|[0-9])?|post\soffice)/i;
    if (addressPattern.test(address)) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }
    args.IsValid = true;
}
```

**Lesson** - The other part of the ***CreateProfile.ascx*** file has Custom Validator in the same format as I posted originally. My superiors feel that Microsoft has done some changes to this probably that is why putting an error message in ***ErrorMessage*** tag does not seem to work. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong somewhere. But if you're someone who is stuck in a similar situation, my solution should help.